# Azure load balancer with IPv6 and IPv4 frontend support

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-load-balancer

Currently my LB has a IPv4 frontend address and one backend pool with 5 VMs with IPv4 private addresses.
We would like to add IPv6 support to our Service Fabric cluster. I found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-ipv6-overview and I see a lot of "Currently not supported" texts.

The IPv6 address is assigned to the LB, but I cannot make rules:

> Failed to save load balancer rule 'rulename'. Error: Frontend ipConfiguration '/subscriptions/...' referring to PublicIp with PublicIpAddressVersion 'IPv6' does not match with PrivateIpAddressVersion 'IPv4' referenced by backend ipConfiguration '/subscriptions/...' for the load balancer rule '/subscriptions/...'.

When I try to add a new backend pool, I get this message:

> One basic SKU load balancer can only be associated with one virtual machine scale set at any point of time

Questions:

1. When can we expect the feature to have multiple LBs before one VMSS?
2. Is it possible to add IPv6 frontend without adding IPv6 to the backend (NAT64?)?
3. Is it possible to add IPv6 addresses to an existing VM scale set without recreating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I am understanding you exactly, It seems that some limitations are in [that article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-ipv6-overview#details-and-limitations).

For your questions:

1. I guess you mean mapping multiple LB frontends to one backend pool. If so, the same frontend protocol and port are reused across multiple frontends since each rule must produce a flow with a unique combination of destination IP address and destination port. You can get more details about [multiple frontend configurations with LB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-multivip-overview).
2. It is not possible. The IP version of the frontend IP address must match the IP version of the target network IP configuration.

> NAT64 (translation of IPv6 to IPv4) is not supported.

3. It is not possible, A VM Scale Set is essentially a group of load balanced VMs. There are a few differences between VM and A Vmss, you can refer to [this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview#differences-between-virtual-machines-and-scale-sets) Also, If a network interface has a private IPv6 address assigned to it, you must add (attach) it to a VM when you **create the VM**. Read the network interface [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-vm#constraints).

> You may not upgrade existing VMs to use IPv6 addresses. You must
>   deploy new VMs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks to me that Azure doesn't support IPv6 very well (yet?). Redeploying the cluster is a hard and difficult job, so for now we will stick to IPv4.

Comment: Currently not well yet, at least some limitations for IPv6. and NAT64 (translation of IPv6 to IPv4) is not supported